# Display values between 0 and 1 as "<1" in Excel Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, number-formatting

I have a set of Excel Pivot tables which are showing sales data in the number of thousands using this format code:

```
#,##0,
```

i.e. £5,000 would display as 5.

The problem with this format is that some sales lines have only generated £499 or less and they display as a zero.

To avoid confusion, I want any sales of £999 or less to be conditionally formatted to display as "<1" - is there a number format that can do this, as well as showing the number of thousands?

Comment: this question is not about programming itself and better suited for [su]

Comment: My apologies, I'm quite new to the site. Thanks for the tip, I'll bear that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom formatting with conditions:

```
[>=1000]#,##0,;"<1"
```

[image]

Comment: np, glad I could help;)